# Exporting all images out of Tabblo

Tags: export, images

Somehow, I got myself involved with a photo sharing site called [Tabblo](http://www.tabblo.com/). I stumbled across my account recently and found a bunch of pictures that I have since lost. There doesn't seem to be any obvious way of exporting all of these images to my local drive and was wondering if anyone had any ideas how to do this.

I'm open to all suggestions as I only expect to do this once. My primary interest is to avoid spending an entire weekend going through all 600+ images downloading them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Firefox [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) plugin you can download every photo from this page:

http://www.tabblo.com/studio/photos/your_user_name/

1. After you installed the plugin, you have to restart the browser.
2. On this page right click, DownThemAll!...
3. Uncheck all filter checkboxes on the bottom and open quick filter
4. Here enter this: download
5. Verify that only those lines are marked that has Download Hi-Resolution photo in the description column. (Carefully deselect the line with logout, as it will log you out while downloading.)

---

- I don't know if Tabblo has pager or something. If it has, you have to repeat these steps on every page.
- I have Hungarian DownThemAll! interface, maybe I have back-translated some text wrong.

Comment: This was just enough "easy" with the right amount of "fast". Thanks!